# What are the consequences of clearing TPM without backing up your data after you encountered Office365 with errors code 80090016?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, tpm

My Office 365 products (Word, PowerPoint, Excel, etc) suddenly produced an error after signing in and trying to reactivate it with my educational email. It said

```
Something went wrong

Your computer's Trusted Platform Module has malfunctioned. If this error persists, contact your system administrator with the error code 80090016.

More information: https://www.microsoft.com/warnerrors

Additional problem information

Error code: 80090016
Correlation ID: **censored**
Timestamp: 2020-10-19T16:13:05Z
More information: https://www.microsoft.com/warnerrors
Server message: Keyset does not exist Keyset does not exist

Continue
```

I've been encountered with this problem lately. I couldn't recall what I was doing specifically before due to this change. It was deactivated and just happened there when I tried to open Word.
I came across with one solution by resolving TPM in this link [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-id/sln319038/microsoft-office-outlook-exchange-error-80090016-after-a-system-board-replacement?lang=en). Another problem that I encountered was I couldn't access another user account since the green bar on the top keeps loading on and on and on. So I asked a friend how to resolve this TPM without log in with another user as an admin and he came up with the idea to clear the TPM from the affected user account like this image below. My question is it safe without back up my entire data on my laptop storage. Could someone guide me or suggest me another worked solution if it is not a good idea?

[where you can find an option to clear TPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOY5j.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to back up your important data before clear TPM, in case the changes bring something unexpected like data loss.

Apart from clearing TPM, please check whether there is update for TPM firmware.
Here is an article about "[Update your security processor (TPM) firmware](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-your-security-processor-tpm-firmware-94205cbc-a492-8d79-cc55-1ecd6b0a8022)", you may have a look.

You may also create a new local administrator account to check this issue.